# QUOTE APPROVAL PROCESS ERROR _ ClassCastException

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, approval-process, error-messages, quote

I found the follow error when a user tries to approve a quote using Salesforce1 app and sending an approval email (quote approval email is correct and approval process is well configured in sfdc org):

*java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number*

Does anyone have the same problem when trying to approve Quotes using this sources?
Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Is it on native SFDC UI and you have no custom page there ? Sounds like salesforce bug to me

Comment: No it's in SFDC UI, there are no custom pages. Do you think we should open a case to Salesforce?